# didConnectPeripheral not called.?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager, cbperipheral

Iam Working on BLE project, I got a sample project which is in this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9v3remiux7jfxus/BLEScanner-Final.zip?dl=0). So when i run on my Device(iPhone 5C),

```
-(void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central
 didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
     advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData
                  RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
```

is called, iam able to get peripheral name, rssi, and some basic details. but after that `didConnectPeripheral` and other CBPeripheral are not called. iam using [EM MicroElectronic coin Beacon](http://www.emmicroelectronic.com/press-release/em-microelectronic-releases-coin-complete-bluetoothr-smart-beacon). Please help me.!

Comment: A pure iBeacon device is not connectable using Core Bluetooth. The first thing I would suggest is download LightBlue and see if that app can connect. If it can then please show he code for your method where you connect.

Comment: can you please check in link.!

Comment: You should add relevant code to your question

Comment: yes i have add code which iam woking on. https://www.dropbox.com/s/9v3remiux7jfxus/BLEScanner-Final.zip?dl=0

Comment: The code should be in your question, not in a file linked to from your question.